# realloc(): invalid next size Aborted (core dumped) and malloc(): unsorted double linked list corrupted

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault, realloc, coredump

I'm trying to print certain lines from files to the console. I'm using a dynamically allocated array to keep track of lines i want to print and if more memory needed i realloc it.

```
void print_with_context(int* arr, char* file, int arr_size){
        if(arr_size == 0)
                return;

        FILE* stream;
        char* line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        int line_number = 1;

        stream = fopen(file, "r");
        if(!stream)
                die("fopen");

        smallest_to_biggest_sort(arr, arr_size);
        int i = 0;
        while(arr[i] <= 0 && i < arr_size) //ignore negative lines
                ++i;

        while(getline(&line, &len, stream) != -1){
                if(i >= arr_size)
                        break;
                if(i > 0){
                        if(arr[i] == arr[i - 1]){
                                ++i;
                                continue;
                        }
                }

                if(arr[i] == line_number){
                        print_cwd(); //print current working directory
                        int success = printf("%s:%d:", file, line_number);
                        if(success < 0)
                                die("printf with context");
                        errno = 0;
                        int line_length = strlen(line);
                        int fwrite_success = fwrite(line, line_length, 1, stdout);
                        if(fwrite_success){
                                if(errno != 0)
                                        die("fwrite");
                        }
                        ++i;
                }
                ++line_number;
        }
        free(line);
        if(fclose(stream))
                die("fclose");

}

void print_regex(struct stat* file_info, regex_t* regex_line, char* file){
        if(!S_ISREG(file_info->st_mode))
                return;
        if(!regex_line)
                return;

        size_t nmatch = 1;
        regmatch_t pmatch[1];

        FILE* stream;
        char* line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        int line_number = 1;

        stream = fopen(file, "r");
        if(!stream)
                die("fopen");

        int* arr = malloc(array_length * sizeof(int));

        if(!arr)
                die("malloc");

        int start = 1, line_found = 0, i = 0;
        while(getline(&line, &len, stream) != -1){
                if(regexec(regex_line, line, nmatch, pmatch, 0) != REG_NOMATCH){
                        ++line_found;
                        if(line_found > resize){
                                ++resize;
                                array_length += 2 * context + 1;
                                errno = 0;
                                arr = realloc(arr, array_length);// <= here fails with the error
                                if(errno == ENOMEM)
                                         die("realloc in print_regex");
                        }

                        start = line_number - context;
                        for(;i < array_length; ++i)
                                arr[i] = start++;
                }
                ++line_number;
        }

        print_with_context(arr, file, i);
        free(arr);
        free(line);
        if(fclose(stream))
                die("fclose");
}
```

I tried debugging it with valgrind but with no success. Here's the output from valgrind:

```
==11041== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11041== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11041== Using Valgrind-3.19.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11041== Command: ./crawl . -line=print* -context=3
==11041== 
==11041== Invalid write of size 4
==11041==    at 0x109E25: print_regex (crawl.c:392)
==11041==    by 0x10A4A2: crawl (crawl.c:518)
==11041==    by 0x10A503: crawl (crawl.c:524)
==11041==    by 0x10A503: crawl (crawl.c:524)
==11041==    by 0x10A82B: main (crawl.c:579)
==11041==  Address 0x4a8824c is 14 bytes after a block of size 14 alloc'd
==11041==    at 0x4846CC3: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11041==    by 0x109DD6: print_regex (crawl.c:385)
==11041==    by 0x10A4A2: crawl (crawl.c:518)
==11041==    by 0x10A503: crawl (crawl.c:524)
==11041==    by 0x10A503: crawl (crawl.c:524)
==11041==    by 0x10A82B: main (crawl.c:579)
==11041== 
--11041-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
--11041-- si_code=1;  Faulting address: 0x3E04A88294;  sp: 0x1002ca9e40

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal

host stacktrace:
==11041==    at 0x5804D09B: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==11041==    by 0x580056B2: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==11041==    by 0x5809B33D: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==11041==    by 0x580E40C0: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 11041)
==11041==    at 0x4846CC3: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11041==    by 0x109DD6: print_regex (crawl.c:385)
==11041==    by 0x10A4A2: crawl (crawl.c:518)
==11041==    by 0x10A503: crawl (crawl.c:524)
==11041==    by 0x10A503: crawl (crawl.c:524)
==11041==    by 0x10A82B: main (crawl.c:579)
client stack range: [0x1FFEFFA000 0x1FFF000FFF] client SP: 0x1FFEFFFC30
valgrind stack range: [0x1002BAA000 0x1002CA9FFF] top usage: 10752 of 1048576
```

It doesn't crash the first time reallocing. It always does crush when it tries to realloc for the 2nd time. When it reallocs just one time it doesn't crush in the function but it does crash in `main()` before finishing the program. One time I also managed to get the **malloc(): unsorted double linked list corrupted** error. So what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "Invalid write of size 4 at 0x109E25: print_regex (crawl.c:392)" <- that is the problem. Valgrind found the problem. Forget about realloc, and fix print_regex (crawl.c:392).

Comment: ```arr = realloc(arr, array_length);``` this is the line it is referring to, which is also in the code i provided above @user253751

Comment: is that line 392?

Comment: yes @user253751

Comment: @yad0: Are you sure? I suspect that `arr = realloc(arr, array_length);` is line 385 and that `arr[i] = start++;` is line 392. Otherwise, the Valgrind log you posted does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are writing to the array out of bounds in the line

```
arr[i] = start++;
```

because the line

```
arr = realloc(arr, array_length);
```

is allocating insufficient memory.

Note that in the line

```
int* arr = malloc(array_length * sizeof(int));
```

you are allocating `array_length * sizeof(int)` bytes, whereas in the line

```
arr = realloc(arr, array_length);
```

you are only allocating `array_length` bytes, i.e. the `* sizeof(int)` part is missing.

Comment: the problem was highly likely the missing sizeof(int) in realloc(). i'm going to try out different outputs and see if i get the error again. if not i'm going to mark your answer as correct. i don't think its arr[i] = start++ because i have also checked it with a debugger multiple times and it never failed there. thank you

Comment: @yad0 do you understand the type of failure? the problem is that `arr[i] = start++` overwrites some memory which does not belong to you (probably belongs to the memory allocator where it keeps its variables) and  then next time you call the memory allocator all its variables have weird values so it crashes.

Comment: @user253751 yes, i do understand failures where you overwrite memory, which doesn't belong to you. in this case however the problem was indeed the missing ```sizeof(int)``` in ```realloc()```

Comment: @yad0 yes, which caused realloc to allocate less memory than you thought, so the latter 3/4ths of it weren't yours even though you thought they were